# Running Chrome as Windows Shell breaks some CSS properties

Tags: google-chrome, windows-shell

We have set Google Chrome to run as the Windows shell by setting it in registry:
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon
Shell = [chrome path]

When run this way, some CSS properties break the page. This renders a blank white page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
* {
    -webkit-perspective: 1000; 
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; 
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
Hello, World
</body>
</html>
```

If you start explorer.exe and refresh the page, it works. Once the page is in a working state, you can also kill explorer.exe and it will keep working.

Have already tried executing runonce.exe with /AlternateShellStartup.

Chrome version 19.0.1084.52 on Windows 7 Professional 64 bit

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following command-line switch for Chrome

```
--disable-accelerated-compositing
```

I had the same problem (not with exactly the CSS properties in the quest, but with some code including webkit-transform, webkit-animation, etc.).  The issue was resolved by disabling accelerated compositing. Also lets it play MP4 video when running as the Windows shell.

Comment: The answer worked well but we have a succession of .mp4 vidoes playing in html5 and now there is a brief black flicker during the transition of one .mp4 video to the next... Any suggestions?